# How can I create a popup dialog box with returnable button values?

Tags: popup

I need a simple true/false verification popup, so I can confirm when a custom JS button has been pressed. I need the true/false value to determine whether or not to perform the function of the button. Anyone have any ideas?

This is a Custom Button on the standard Contacts object.

Comment: Lighting, Visualforce, something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this about what you're looking for?

```
if(confirm('Are you sure you want to do that?')){
    alert('I never doubted you for a second!');
}
else{
    alert('I knew you\'d change your mind.');
}
```

Comment: Ever have one of those DUH moments? :)